# Express JS - Reset cookie expiration time

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am using express-session to manage sessions. I am using this:

```
    app.use(session({secret: 'secret',
                     resave: false,
                     saveUninitialized: false,
                     cookie: { maxAge: 6*1000 
                             }
                    })
            );
```

Now I want reset the expiration value to 6 every time my url is hit. So I do this:

```
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 6000
```

But the max age is not reset and the session expires in 6 seconds always even if the url is hit. How do I change this to 6000 every time?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Try req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 6000); I haven't tried this though.

Comment: Well that is strange i've just tried it and it works as expected. Cookie's expires value is updated with each page refresh.

Comment: Ohhh my bad... I did not set rolling property as true...

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a middleware, my code is very simple but it works fine for me

```js
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  req.session._garbage = Date();
  req.session.touch();
  next()
})
```

I put that code in app.js and works great for me

This is my session code:

```
app.use(session({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 14400000
  },
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  secret: config.sessionSecret,
  store: new RedisStore({
    port: 6379
  })
}));
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem, what is `req.session._garbage` by the way?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this example it may be helpful you

Update your code like this

```
req.session._garbage = Date();
req.session.touch();  
req.session.cookie.expires = 2592000000; // 30*24*60*60*1000 Rememeber 'me' for 30 days
```

For your reference please check the bellow examples

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'iloveyoudear...',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {expires: 30*24*60*60*1000 }
}));
```

OR

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'iloveyoudear...',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: 30*24*60*60*1000 }
}));
```

Above two examples not working please set individually like this in your router

```
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 2592000000; // 30*24*60*60*1000 Rememeber 'me' for 30 days
```

This one also not working please check your

> express-session and cookie-parser npm versions and install latest version

All examples working for me , please look at one bellow snapshot .

[image]